# Move and rename the files - bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm new to unix shell/bash scripting . My requirement is as follows :

The current directory contains a **lot of dynamic folders** and the data file is available only in the last sub folder.

**I need to move the data file to the home folder and rename the datafile's name as the current directory's name.**

Could you please help in writing the bash script for the same.

**--update--**

I tried the following to move file to the parent directory:

```
     find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `find`? Have you tried anything?

Comment: What are the dynamic folders' names? What is the datafile's original name?

Comment: @choroba : The folders have junk names like 1e4be6fdbea37f8d-ca16ccde69d5779f_476244713_data.0

Comment: If there are more than one data files how can they both be renamed to same directory name?

Comment: The final subfolder has only 1 file, always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out many options , the following worked

```
     find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv {} . \;
     dirFullPath=`pwd`
     fileName=`echo $dirFullPath | awk -F"/" '{print $(NF)}'`
     mv *.0 $fileName.tab
```

Any other better solutions is appreciated, Thanks.!!